# Why I am rendering to main page when I work on current page using routing

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using the following code in visual studio. Here is the routing part when I click to FAQ component through page component and perform according in FAQ component backs to page component.

```
    Here is routing part
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { PageComponent } from './components/page/page.component';
    import { FaqComponent } from './Folder/faq/faq.component';
    import { HomeComponent } from './Folder/home/home.component';

    const routes: Routes = [
      
      {path: 'login', component: HomeComponent },

      {path: 'data', component: FaqComponent },
      { path: '', component: PageComponent },


    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

FaqComponent=>PageComponent

data => /

```html
<a routerLink="/">xxx</a>
```